# Изменение размерности 2d матрицы при фурье преобразовании

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, fft

Мне нужно сделать преобразование фурье от картинки. Я заполнил единицами контур круга в массиве z и попытался сделать от него `rfft2(z, (250, 250))`. 
Не понимаю, почему размерность выходного массива не совпадает с размерностью входного. Я не могу отрисовать получившийся результат.

```
def plot_amplitude(x, y, z):
    z_max = np.max(z)
    z_min = np.min(z)
    plt.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap='gray', vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max,
               label="Амплитуда")
    plt.show()

size = 1.2
count = 250
x = np.linspace(-size, size, count)
y = np.linspace(-size, size, count)
z = np.zeros([len(x), len(y)])
print(z.shape)
#plot_amplitude(x, y, z)

# заполняю функцию z(x,y) рисунком в форме круга
t = np.linspace(0 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 10000)
xparam = np.sin(t)
yparam = np.cos(t)
for i in range(len(xparam)):
    indx = int(xparam[i] // (2 * size / count) + len(x) / 2)
    indy = int(yparam[i] // (2 * size / count) + len(y) / 2)
    z[indx, indy] = 1

print(z.shape)
z2 = rfft2(z, (250, 250))
print(z2.shape)
#plot_amplitude(x, y, z2)
```

Код выводит в консоль:

```
(250, 250)
(250, 126)
```

В свою очередь, с обратным фурье `irfft2(z, (250, 250))` проблем нет:

```
z1 = irfft2(z, (250, 250))
print(z1.shape)
plot_amplitude(x, y, z1)
```

Вывод:

```
(250, 250)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004818/5741205